# Python CSV: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'partition'

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to remove all characters after the "@" character.
From this text file.

```
TheSwankyGamer@gmail.com
TheTallGamer@gmail.com
ThePresentGamer@gmail.com
```

This is what I have done so far.

```
import csv

with open('found.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='.')
    for row in spamreader:
        head, sep, tail = row.partition('@')
        print(head)

        print(' '.join(row))
```

It gives me this error:

```
 head, sep, tail = row.partition('@')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'partition'
```

Why does it gives me this error and how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

CSV reader returns the row as a `list`. Since you're using `.` as the separtor. You will get a list like: `['TheSwankyGamer@gmail', 'com']`

Now if you want the name from that, you can split the first entry in the list by `@` and get it.

```
import csv

with open('found.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='.')
    for row in spamreader:
        head, tail = row[0].split('@')
        print(head)
        print(' '.join(row))
```

Output:

```
TheSwankyGamer
TheSwankyGamer@gmail com
TheTallGamer
TheTallGamer@gmail com
ThePresentGamer
ThePresentGamer@gmail com
```